# Remove/Modify an inherited ACE in an ACL (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, acl

I'm trying to modify the existing ACL on a directory (and its sub-directories) to remove write access for the built-in Users group.  The directory is inheriting this particular right from its parent directory.  I've tried using AtlSetDacl() to set a new ACL but this doesn't clear out the inherited write permission.  Fragment:

```
ATL::CDacl dacl;
ATL::AtlGetDacl(directoryName.c_str(), SE_FILE_OBJECT, &dacl);
UINT aceCount = dacl.GetAceCount();
ATL::CDacl newDacl;
for (UINT i = 0; i < aceCount; ++i)
{
   ATL::CSid sid;
   ACCESS_MASK mask = 0;
   BYTE flags = 0;
   dacl.GetAclEntry(i,
                    &sid,
                    &mask,
                    (BYTE*) 0,
                    &flags);
   if (sid != Sids::Users())
       newDacl.AddAllowedAce(sid, mask, flags);
}
newDacl.AddAllowedAce(Sids::Users(),FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY | FILE_READ_EA | FILE_EXECUTE | FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE | OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE);
AtlSetDacl(directoryName.c_str(), SE_FILE_OBJECT, newDacl);
```

I've also tried SetNamedSecurityInfo() and related APIs to wipe the existing ACL and create a new one, but no luck here either.  Doesn't seem like this should be that hard.  Using cacls.exe this is a piece of cake (unfortunately not an option for me).  Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Is this the actual code?  Because you construct newDacl with the omitted ACE and then set the (old) dacl back on the directory.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, dave. Was working with too many versions and pasted the wrong version. Fixed the code block. This is the code that is not doing what I expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To remove inherited ACEs, call [SetNamedSecurityInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and pass `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` for the SecurityInfo parameter.

The `PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` flag prevents inheritable ACEs from the parent from being added to the ACL you specify.

If you don't need to copy other inherited permissions, but can just specify a particular ACL to use, that would be simpler.   If you do need to copy other inherited permissions, you'll need to keep the read-compare-add loop in your existing code, but you should also be clearing the INHERITED_ACE flag since these are now explicit permissions.